# make netbeans respect tab settings

Tags: java, netbeans, tabs, settings, netbeans-6.9

How can I make NetBeans (6.9.1) respect my tab preference of 4 spaces for java files (that's the standard at my company).  Some pages where I've tried saving this setting:

```
1) Netbeans > Preferences > Editor > Formatting > Languages: All Languages
2) Netbeans > Preferences > Editor > Formatting > Languages: java
3) [my project] > Properties > Formatting > Languages: All Languages
4) [my project] > Properties > Formatting > Languages: Java
```

Some of these settings work temporarily for the file I have immediately open, but as soon as I click another tab and come back, it always resets to the default 8 again.

Any advice?

(PS - I'm posting here by default simply because I have yet to find a decent or active NB forum)

Comment: "*I have yet to find a decent or active NB forum*": what about: http://forums.netbeans.org/index.php

Comment: right_click on code then Format (or Alt+Shift+F)